# How to count a number on in Elixir without built in function such as Enum.count?

Tags: count, elixir

How to count a number on in Elixir without built-in function such as Enum.count. Here is my code, Thanks so much

```
defmodule Ans do
  @my_favorite_number 0

 def sum([]) do
    0
  end
  def sum([head|tail]) do
    head + sum(tail)

  end

  def average([head|tail]) do
    total = sum([head|tail])
    iterations = Enum.count([head|tail])
    output = total / iterations
  end

  end
```

Answer (score 3):

You should read about tail-call optimization. The compiler makes use of this optimisation to prevent a new stack frame being created every recursive call, which will happen in your code. Here is an example of how to write the `sum/1` function in a tail-recursive way. The main idea is to keep the return in an `accumulator` variable that is passed to each call, instead of building up the answer in the call stack:

```elixir
def sum(list), do: sum(0, list)
def sum(acc, []), do: acc
def sum(acc, [head | tail]), do: sum(acc + head, tail)
```

For `count`, you can do something similar, but just add `1` instead of the value of the list item:

```elixir
def count(list), do: count(0, list)
def count(acc, []), do: acc
def count(acc, [_head | tail]), do: count(acc + 1, tail)
```

Comment: thanks :) here is my edit code :   `def len([]) , do: 0
  def len( [_head | tail] ) , do: 1 + len(tail)`

Comment: That works fine! But when you start getting into problems with big numbers due to stack overflow, come back again and and read about tail-call optimization. :)

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Erlang and Elixir seem not having a limit on stack depth, so I never saw a stack overflow. My RAM blows up first.

Comment: @Aetherus Interesting. Indeed, I may have been peddling a myth: http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html and also looks like I misunderstood about the call stack too: http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html#myth--beam-is-a-stack-based-byte-code-virtual-machine------and-therefore-slow- Thanks for the pointer! Looks like it's still good to use tail recursion in these cases though, because they do not need to reverse the list so can avoid creating any terms.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip You're right about tail recursion, of course. Though non-tail recursion doesn't cause stack overflow, it does cause other problems.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Oh, and thank you for the links to the myth buster.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer by Adam is perfectly correct, to calculate the *average* you might do better (in one loop,) using more sophisticated accumulator.

```rb
defmodule M do
  def avg(list), do: do_avg({0, 0}, list)

  defp do_avg({cnt, sum}, []),
    do: sum / cnt
  defp do_avg({cnt, sum}, [h | t]),
    do: do_avg({cnt + 1, sum + h}, t)
end 

M.avg [1,2,3,4]
#⇒ 2.5
```

Here we do accumulate *both* count and total and calculate an average on the last step when the list is exhausted.

Also, you might return everything, as a tuple `{cnt, sum, sum / cnt}`, or as a map for better readability.